# at what point does a unit test become an integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

A unit test involves testing the smallest units of an application.  So a unit test could be written against a UserRepository to test a GetAllUsers() method.

A unit test could also be written against a UserDomain to test a GetAllUsers() method. Since UserDomain calls down into UserRepository would the UserDomain test be considered an integration test?

Or would the UserDomain test be considered a unit test if there is a service layer which provides the API into the backend?

Comment: It's an integration test if it involves two or more units.

Comment: Based on your experience, do a lot of dev shops create unit tests at the Domain layer and integration tests at the Service layer?  Basically they skip unit tests at the Repo layer due to diminishing returns?

Comment: focus on unit testing the logic inside your code; the data access layer is probably lean enough to only hit it through integration tests

Answer (score 2):

if you're testing `UserDomain` which relies on `UserRepository` then you aren't coding to an interface, but rather a concretion/implementation.  This in turn couples the two together.  Coupled code means hard to unit test code, as there is no testing `UserDomain` without `UserRepository`.

In your example, you likely have something like this:

```
public class UserDomain
{
    public object GetAllUsers()
    {
        UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();
        var results = repo.GetAllUsers();
        // do some stuff like transforming it
        return null;
    }
}

public class UserRepository
{
    public object GetAllUsers()
    {
        return null; // implementation
    }
}
```

The problem with coding in this approach is you cannot really "unit test" `UserDomain`, as it relies on `UserRepository`.  In order to accomplish real unit testing, your pieces have to not be reliant on implementations, but rather abstractions like interfaces.

To accomplish unit testing, your classes can look more like:

```
public class UserDomain
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _iUserRepository;

    public UserDomain(IUserRepository iUserRepository)
    {
        _iUserRepository = iUserRepository;
    }

    public object GetAllUsers()
    {
        var results = _iUserRepository.GetAllUsers();
        // do some stuff like transforming it
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IUserRepository
{
    object GetAllUsers();
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public object GetAllUsers()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note not a whole lot has really changed here once you understand what you're looking at.  We created a new interface `IUserRepository` which `UserRepository` now implements.  `UserDomain` was also updated to rather than new up a specific implementation (`UserRepository`), take in an instance of `IUserRepository`.

This means a few things, `UserDomain` is no longer directly dependent on `UserRepository`, it now relies on an abstraction `IUserRepository`, which can be easily mocked, stubbed, or faked out in order to provide test functionality for testing purposes.

The concept of passing in implementations of your interfaces in the constructor is known as [dependency injection](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-dependency-injection-and-ioc-containers).  Constructor injection is one method of accomplishing dependency injection, but there are others as well.  The basic idea of it is if a class has dependencies, those dependencies should be on interfaces/contracts, and not literal implementations.

With all of that said, an integration test is a test that uses actual implementations like `UserRepository` within the scope of `UserDomain`, rather than your stubbed, mocked, faked `IUserRepository`.